# Missing MEDIA_LIBRARY permissions

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf, permissions, file-permissions

I making an app using **react native expo**, onPress I want to download a **.vcf or .pdf** file on specified folder which is I fetched from server. but when I click onPress I get following errors in console
I able to download Images but when it comes to .vcf or pdf file facing below error.

```
MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("xFolderName", asset);
```

**xFolderName** where Im trying to store my .vcf or .pdf file, following path is created while saving an Images same for .vcf file **Android-> Pictures -> xFolderName**

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: **MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync**
> must be called with an asset on Android.]

**at node_modules/expo-media-library/build/MediaLibrary.js:302:14 in createAlbumAsync
at node_modules/expo-media-library/build/MediaLibrary.js:295:7 in createAlbumAsync
at components/ngo/ECard.js:98:8 in FileSystem.downloadAsync.then$argument_0**

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Missing MEDIA_LIBRARY
> permissions.]

**at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:106:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/NativeModulesProxy.native.js:15:23 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at node_modules/expo-media-library/build/MediaLibrary.js:148:24 in createAssetAsync
at node_modules/expo-media-library/build/MediaLibrary.js:141:7 in createAssetAsync
at components/ngo/ECard.js:97:22 in FileSystem.downloadAsync.then$argument_0**

**App.js**

```
import { Header } from "react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView,
    Modal,
    Share,
    ImageBackground,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { API_URL } from "@env";
import { Icon, SocialIcon } from "@rneui/themed";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as MediaLibrary from "expo-media-library";
import Toast from "react-native-root-toast";

export default function App(props) {
    const [apiData, setApiData] = React.useState({
        xxxname: "",
    });

    const downloadFile = () => {
        FileSystem.downloadAsync(
            `${API_URL}/xpath/xpath?slug=${apiData.slug}`,
            FileSystem.documentDirectory + apiData.xname + ".vcf"
        )
            .then(({ uri }) => {
                const asset = MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
                MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("xFolderName", asset);
                Toast.show("Download Completed");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

    };

    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.addButton}
                onPress={() => downloadFile()}
            >
                <Icon
                    color={"white"}
                    name="file-download"
                />
                <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>Download</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    addButton: {
        width: "30%",
        margin: 10,
        height: 55,
        backgroundColor: "#3b82f6",
        borderRadius: 15,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        elevation: 8,
    },
    addButtonText: {
        color: "#fff",
        fontSize: 18,
    },
});
```